# Может ли бот отправлять изображения без compress image?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Как с помощью библиотеки `aiogram` отправлять сообщения без сжатия, как на фото?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте [send_document](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/methods/send_document.html)